# shortcut for changing radius of circle select

Tags: interface

Is there any chance (or add-on) so that i can change the circle radius of "circle select" quickly?

Really great would be e.g. holding control and just moving the mouse up and down.

[image]

I am searching for a mouse/trackpad solution because i am working on a Macbook (no Numpad ‍♂️)

Comment: Either scroll the mousewheel or there's an addon described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHxQ0k_DC8Q).

Comment: unfortunately i am on a macbook - if you know a workaround for scrolling...pls tell me. The add-on would be great if it would work with touchpad/mouse move

Comment: Use Numpad + and - buttons

Comment: Always say what machine you're using! You should know that by now @Chris! :^) Does a Macbook have a numpad? - The addons I found seem to suggest that's how they work as Christopher says.

Comment: @JohnEason: you are totally right. Of course i have no numpad. And of course i am searching for a mouse/trackpad solution

Comment: @Chris While looking at videos of addons, I've realised that you can change the Select circle radius from the N panel on the Tool tab which might be of use to you! I've always used the scroll wheel under Windows so I'd never thought to look there before.

Comment: On a trackpad, try to swipe with 2 fingers to increase and decrease the circle size.

Comment: @Blunder: I tried this so many times. it never worked. I have no idea why it works now. Maybe because of the keymap change. But i am happy i can now change it via trackpad which is for me the most elegant and quick solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to do it with mouse movements because this is needed for the selection of geometry, e.g. Here is another solution with two shortcuts:

Add two KeymapItems in Preferences > Keymap > View3D Gesture Circle:

[image]

Single steps:

1. Add New > select `Add` in PropertyValue > (default mapping = `Keyboard`, default event = `A`, nothing to do) > expand KeyMapItem > tick `Repeat`
2. Add New > select `Subtract` in PropertyValue > (default mapping = `Keyboard`, nothing to do) > click event (button right) > press `S` on keyboard > expand
   KeyMapItem > tick `Repeat`

In screenshot I have disabled the old `Add/Subtract` items with events `Numpad +/-`and `Wheel Up/Down` if they do not work for you.
In Circle Select Mode now, if at least one vertice is selected and LMB is hold, the selection radius can be changed with `A` for add and `S` for subtract. Tested in 2.9.3 and 3.3.0

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I really hoped for a similar functionality in sculpting. You just press F and then you can size it with your mouse. That's very fast and intuitive - i think. But anyway you got my right answer click - until someone can show me a better/easier solution ;) But your answer is very useful to me because it is a strong improvement for me.

Comment: Wow! I didn´t know about this function. The mousewheel doesn't work in sculpt mode and I needed to change the radius also by properties. Till now. And in fact it´s very pleasant and works in particle edit mode as well. Thank you very much for this clue.